# Excel how do i set a fixed size mask in a cell with chars and numbers

Tags: excel, mask

I want to count the cells in a table within the following text:

```
something_abc5
something_abc09
something_abc14
```

right now I'm using:

```
COUNTIF(Table1[[#All],[Tag1]],"*"&"_abc"&"*")
```

However I need it to not count this:

`something_abcd` or `something_abc5d`

the number can have 1 or 2 digits but no chars after.

I've already tried with "*"&"_abc"&0 but I get no results

Comment: You can use `?` as a single character wildcard but not sure you can distinguish numbers from text in COUNTIF.

Comment: it limits to one character (i could use an OR to count 2 also) however it counts also text :\

Comment: Think you'll need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
=Text(12,"0000") = 0012
=Text(1,"0000") = 0001
```

That should probably do what you're looking for. Concatenates well:

```
="ABC"&Text(1,"00") = ABC01
```